# Using R package plusser to get followers of a page/profile

Tags: r, google-plus

I want to find the number of followers on a Google+ page.

I will be using R package "plusser" for that.

Code will be as - http://decisionstats.com/2014/06/26/analysing-google-plus-posts-using-r-language-rstats/

I want to know if there is any way I can find the followers on a page.

The document for plusser is at cran.

The link for Google API is - https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource

Its response provides "**circledByCount**". But not the number of followers.

Can anyone tell how can I find number of followers on google+ page using R?

Comment: I suggest you embed all the code you've tried here, along with where you get stuck. As the question stands right now it could be closed as "looking for a tutorial".

Comment: `circledByCount` is the number of followers a page/person has. It is not always public though.

Comment: @Abraham , as per google api, circledByCount is  the number of people who have added this person or page to a circle.   So, if I want the count of followers of a person, circledByCount will provide that ?

Comment: That's how you follow someone, by adding them to a circle.

Answer (score 1):

A page is not people.  If you really do mean a Google+ Page then you need to request access to the Google+ pages api.   I don't have access to this API so I don't know if you can see that for a page.

> The Google+ pages API allows social media management companies to add
>   Google+ page management features into their tool. Access to this API
>   is available through a whitelist, and access is granted to partners on
>   a company by company basis dependent on fit with this API. If you are
>   a social media management company interested in getting access to this
>   API, please complete the form below with details about your company's
>   platform. Please answer all questions below accurately; any inaccurate
>   information that misrepresents your tool can affect your company's
>   access to this API. If your company is a fit for this API's
>   functionality, the Google+ team will reach out to the contact provided
>   in this form with next steps. Please do not submit multiple entries to
>   this form.

[Google Pages API - Partner Application Form](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup)

If you in fact mean a person and you for example want to see who has me circled.  You cant that's not available in the API at this time.

the best you can do is see how many people have me circled [circledByCount](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)

Comment: The Pages API is mostly for posting as that page. Getting info about a page and profile are the same people.get API that is public though.

Comment: I agree with what @Abraham has said.